# react/prop-types error on TS type for unknown object structure

Tags: typescript, eslint, react-proptypes

Puzzling eslint error. I have an unknown object structure passed into a component like so:

```
type Props = {
    i18n: {
        [key: string]: string;
    }
};

const Comp = ({ i18n }: Props) => (
    ...
    // i18n.myPropertyName
);
```

Referencing i18n.myPropertyName yields the following error:

```
19:55  error  'i18n.myPropertyName' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types
```

What do I need to do to make it accept any object structure? I thought my TS type def was correct.

Comment: If you use typed components - you don't need `react/prop-types`. What it wants from you is to declare the `propTypes` explicitly: `Comp.propTypes = { ... }`